# The order of convergence and the asymptotic error constant of the sequence $p_n=g(p_{n-1})$

Tags: numerical-methods, asymptotics

> Let $g(x)=0.5(x+a/x)$. Determine the order of convergence and the asymptotic error constant of the sequence $p_n=g(p_{n-1})$ toward $x=a^{.5}$.

This is a problem in our homework in the class Numerical Analysis and our teacher never went over anything like this at all so I have no idea. You don't have to give me the answer, but I could really use to advice on how to approach this problem.

Answer (score 1):

Here's hint:

$$\left|g(x)-\sqrt{a}\right| = \frac{\left(x-\sqrt{a}\right)^2}{2 x}.$$

Thus, if $|x-\sqrt{a}|$ is small, then $|g(x)-\sqrt{a}|$ is small squared - i.e. *really* small.

Incidentally, this sequence arises from the application of Newton's method to the function $f(x)=x^2-a$.

Comment: what about the asymptotic error?

Comment: @Brian Think about it. The hint addresses both the fact of  convergence and the rate of convergence. At some point you've got to stop blaming your teacher with copy-pasted statements and take some responsibility for your learning.